# Correct method of pushing to a TreeScale docker registry from local

Tags: docker

I've created an account with TreeScale my docker pull address for my newly created registry is

```
docker pull repo.treescale.com/ar/ar-nodejs
```

Attempting to commit a local docker container to the registry I follow these steps :

1.

```
docker tag ar-nodejs repo.treescale.com/ar/7565080bd49b
```

where `ar-nodejs` is image name and `7565080bd49b` is container id.

2.

To push to the TreeScale registry I use :

```
docker push ar-nodejs
```

But receive error :

```
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/library/ar-nodejs]
3bf1f19d5b50: Preparing 
e14577d2cac5: Preparing 
e8829d5bbd2c: Preparing 
674ce3c5d814: Preparing 
308b39a73046: Preparing 
638903ee8579: Waiting 
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

I'm logged into the registry as per :

```
~# docker login repo.treescale.com
username: [TreeScale username]
password: [TreeScale password]
```

Source : https://docs.treescale.com/container-registry/usage.html

Am I tagging and pushing to the TreeScale registry correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The container ID is not useful information.  I would do:

```
docker tag ar-nodejs repo.treescale.com/ar/ar-nodejs
docker push repo.treescale.com/ar/ar-nodejs
```

A version numbering scheme should no be discarded, though.

Answer (score 0):

After login, use this:

```
docker tag 7565080bd49b treescale.com/ar/ar-nodejs:myversion

docker push treescale.com/ar/ar-nodejs:myversion
```

Where `myversion` is whatever version name you wanna create

Comment: thanks, but using "docker tag 7565080bd49b treescale.com/ar/ar-nodejs:myversion" returns "Error response from daemon: No such image: 7565080bd49b:latest"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The reason was, that I named the image originally

```
someImageName:version
```

but as you see from your docker response there:

```
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/library/ar-nodejs]
```

--> Docker was trying to push it to the dockerhub, not treescale!

You need to rename your image to include the repo address, so:

```
someImageName:version
```

becomes:

```
repo.treescale.com/<yourUsername>/someImageName:version
```

then it worked for me